# Google API Places Details not showing pictures shown in Google+ Page

Tags: google-places-api

I can see photos on the Google+ Places Pages, but it's those pictures are not retrieved within the Google API Places Details json response. Not all places, but some places are showing this behavior. As an example, I'll give you the Google+ Page for an Hotel and show you the json response retrieved:

Google+ Page

https://plus.google.com/104205878124399481073/about

```
{
   "debug_info" : [],
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "result" : {
      "address_components" : [
         {
            "long_name" : "Ret. 3 Lotes 12 y 13",
            "short_name" : "Ret. 3 Lotes 12 y 13",
            "types" : [ "street_number" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Paseo Xaman-ha",
            "short_name" : "Paseo Xaman-ha",
            "types" : [ "route" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Villas Pakal",
            "short_name" : "Villas Pakal",
            "types" : [ "sublocality", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Playa del Carmen",
            "short_name" : "Playa del Carmen",
            "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Quintana Roo",
            "short_name" : "Quintana Roo",
            "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "MX",
            "short_name" : "MX",
            "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "77710",
            "short_name" : "77710",
            "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
         }
      ],
      "formatted_address" : "Paseo Xaman-ha Ret. 3 Lotes 12 y 13, Villas Pakal, Playa del Carmen, Quintana Roo, México",
      "formatted_phone_number" : "01 984 803 1585",
      "geometry" : {
         "location" : {
            "lat" : 25.855920,
            "lng" : -97.4760320
         }
      },
      "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/lodging-71.png",
      "id" : "98e0009b05c90782c18e8c12273d651c0dde3d5a",
      "international_phone_number" : "+52 984 803 1585",
      "name" : "Hotel Hacienda Vista Real",
      "opening_hours" : {
         "open_now" : true,
         "periods" : [
            {
               "close" : {
                  "day" : 0,
                  "time" : "2359"
               },
               "open" : {
                  "day" : 0,
                  "time" : "0000"
               }
            },
            {
               "close" : {
                  "day" : 1,
                  "time" : "2359"
               },
               "open" : {
                  "day" : 1,
                  "time" : "0000"
               }
            },
            {
               "close" : {
                  "day" : 2,
                  "time" : "2359"
               },
               "open" : {
                  "day" : 2,
                  "time" : "0000"
               }
            },
            {
               "close" : {
                  "day" : 3,
                  "time" : "2359"
               },
               "open" : {
                  "day" : 3,
                  "time" : "0000"
               }
            },
            {
               "close" : {
                  "day" : 4,
                  "time" : "2359"
               },
               "open" : {
                  "day" : 4,
                  "time" : "0000"
               }
            },
            {
               "close" : {
                  "day" : 5,
                  "time" : "2359"
               },
               "open" : {
                  "day" : 5,
                  "time" : "0000"
               }
            },
            {
               "close" : {
                  "day" : 6,
                  "time" : "2359"
               },
               "open" : {
                  "day" : 6,
                  "time" : "0000"
               }
            }
         ]
      },
      "reference" : "CoQBdwAAALAyGQMoVRlq-UMhh0CFSKHKyHFI4jbA_H5zhwCK5r9haJFCgx7Y0Ql_rWiSap3Tao6QHpfRaKy3dpmaOuwkLCuNeoeVRhkWZWHIb_kN0phGdg1-CbJp3au7KKq8_C8LHYccrYg6sPYDSs7nblWh_xvbbNHtf2N30O_YppCjQp8BEhBKMZnaMDqKN3LMOddPNlpyGhTL3mQ_-HM5r2893_pWitrdOcX6vQ",
      "reviews" : [
         {
            "aspects" : [
               {
                  "rating" : 1,
                  "type" : "quality"
               },
               {
                  "rating" : 1,
                  "type" : "facilities"
               },
               {
                  "rating" : 2,
                  "type" : "service"
               }
            ],
            "author_name" : "Yuri Diana Mateos",
            "author_url" : "https://plus.google.com/105503150293220587391",
            "text" : "Incribisisisimo el paseo chido quien bota por jaltipan",
            "time" : 1366422681
         }
      ],
      "types" : [ "lodging", "establishment" ],
      "url" : "https://plus.google.com/104205878124399481073/about?hl=en-US",
      "utc_offset" : -300,
      "vicinity" : "Paseo Xaman-ha Ret. 3 Lotes 12 y 13, Villas Pakal, Playa del Carmen",
      "website" : "http://www.eurostarshaciendavistareal.com/"
   },
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be doing everything correctly, but the data simply isn't there.  You might create a defect issue (if this hasn't already been reported) so that they know about the problem and can look into it.

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list